# zend-framework problem using routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

UPDATE:

Turns out it's not only the routing, but any instance of going 'up' a directory.

For example `mysite.com/public` serves me the correct index.phtml file...
`mysite.com/index/testpage` DOES serve me the testpage.phtml, but my directory structure is completely screwed and I lose all links to images & Stylesheets etc. I've checked my .htaccess and it's exactly as recommended.

Serious head-scratching time here...

**OP:**

Hello..

I'm using this method for catching urls and serving up the correct content

```
$router->addRoute(
    'list',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/list', array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=> 'list'))
    );
```

And it works really well, serves up the content from list.phtml...

but, the moment I attempt anything 'up' a directory such as this I lose all my style sheets and other relative scripts.

```
$router->addRoute(
    'listWithUsers',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/list/:users', array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=> 'list'))
    );
```

It's strange because I can access the `users` variable and `echo` it to screen, it's just that I lose all scripts and stylesheets whenever a URL contains `/`

For clarity, I'm able to set actions in the `indexController.php` to catch URLS and it works, but it seems to serve it as another directory causing me to lose all relative links.

Thanks for any help. Please advise if any specific details would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any kind of MVC app using routes like this, you have to specify absolute path for your resources. This will prevent the issue you have.

For example, if I have a website located at `mysite.com/app1` and I have a resource located in `lib/jquery-1.2.6.min.js`, then a valid path will be `/app1/lib/jquery-1.2.6.min.js`.

For this I have always used some kind of helper to return the site's base URL in my views.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/lib/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

You can use [a view helper](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) or a constant.

Comment: This works. Many thanks for your help. I was aware of the need for absolute paths, but was following along with Zend Screencasts and there were no absolute paths used. Either way my Application is working now. Thanks. For archives sake - `echo $this->baseUrl()` worked for me, not `echo $this->getBaseUrl()`